# Test 200 code in python/django

Tags: python, django, testing, cookies

I'm trying to test my project and I want to get a 200 status code with the following test:

```
import unittest
from django.test import Client
from views2 import *
import requests


class TestCharts(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_200(self):

        url_csrftoken = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/'
        url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
        url_login = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/signin'
        client = requests.session()
        client.get(url_csrftoken)
        csrftoken = client.cookies['csrftoken']
        login_data = dict(inputUser='admin', inputPassword='mypass', csrfmiddlewaretoken=csrftoken, next=url)
        client.post(url_login, data=login_data)
        r = client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(r.status_code,200)

if __name__ == '__main__':


    print "Testing"
    unittest.main()
```

It stops at: `client.get(url_csrftoken)` and gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests2.py", line 115, in test_networking
    csrftoken = client.cookies['csrftoken']
  File "/home/user/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/cookies.py", line 327, in __getitem__
    return self._find_no_duplicates(name)
  File "/home/user/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/cookies.py", line 398, in _find_no_duplicates
    raise KeyError('name=%r, domain=%r, path=%r' % (name, domain, path))
KeyError: "name='csrftoken', domain=None, path=None"
```

But I don't unserstand what's going on.

Comment: That's not how you test Django apps. Did you read any of the comprehensive testing documentation?

Comment: @DanielRoseman is right. you should firstly read [DOCS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/overview/) and then if you have problems return here with another question.

Comment: But not in any useful way. Why are you using requests to test your app?

Comment: Really? This is how I was taught to do it.

Comment: Please read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/tools/#the-test-client

Comment: Yes... I understand, but that approach didn't work for me:
I get "No handlers could be found for logger "django.request"" and "AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet." errors

Comment: For a start, use `django.test.SimpleTestCase` (or `TestCase` if the database is involved) instead of `unittest.TestCase`, and run your tests using `manage.py test` - Django needs to do all sorts of magic to make it's internals work, so you can't just import bits of it from any framework